# Equation for Cube Edge-Lenth y that results in n-number of points with spacing x

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I would need to find an equation that gives me the edge length *l* of a 3D cube that results in a specific number of points *n* inside the cube when their spacing is *x*. It's probably similar to the below but in 3D and simpler as edge length in XYZ is constant. For now, I assume that the point spacing *x* in XYZ is constant.

[How to evenly space a number of points in a rectangle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039482/how-to-evenly-space-a-number-of-points-in-a-rectangle)

For constant d as described by @achille hui

l=x⌈(n^(1/3))−1⌉

How would this change for different x along different dimensions?

Comment: Wouldn't something like $\frac {n^{\frac 1 3}}x=\frac {\sqrt[3]{n}}x$ be what you're looking for?

Comment: That would result in a smaller edge length for larger point spacing x?

Comment: I got this backwards, $x$ is spacing, not density. Then $x\sqrt[3]{n}$ is probably what you want.

Comment: A cube of size $k x$ can hold $(k+1)^3$ points which lie on a cubic lattice of separation $x$. So for a given $n$, a cube of size  $l = x\left\lceil n^{1/3} - 1\right\rceil$ can hold $n$ points in such a cubic lattice. You can pack the points more densely (ie. a smaller $l$) if you allow a different arrangement of points.

Comment: Good stuff - that should work. Thank you!

Comment: How would this get change if I would assume the same d in two dimensions but a different x in the third?

Comment: For three different spacings $x, y, z$ in the cardinal directions, you can modify the formula to $l = \sqrt[3]{xyz}\left\lceil n^{1/3} - 1\right\rceil$. Note that this does not guarantee you will get exactly $n$ points inside. Only certain $n$ can be exactly obtained. For general $n$, this gives the smallest number of points possible that is $\ge n$.

Comment: Merci! That is all I need.